# Modify object outside of a write transaction

Tags: swift, realm

I know there is a lot of threads about this topic, but think mine is a bit different, becouse I am not saving or fetching objects from the DB and they are on main Thread all the time.

My problem is pretty werid, I can modify realm object in the same class but when I pass it as an argument to another then the stuffs like that occure. I am trying to understand why is that happening ? It should not occure.

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
```

Here is my data base structure:

1. **Persistable** is a protocol which is shared by each object in data base.

   ```
       public protocol Persistable {
           associatedtype PropertyValue: PropertyValueType
           associatedtype ManagedObject: RealmSwift.Object
           associatedtype Query: QueryType

           init(managedObject: ManagedObject)

           func getManagedObject() -> ManagedObject
       }

       public typealias PropertyValuePair = (name: String, value: Any)

       public protocol PropertyValueType {
           var propertyValuePair: PropertyValuePair { get }
       }

       public protocol QueryType {
           var predicate: NSPredicate? { get }
           var sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor] { get }
       }
   ```
2. **Container** class:

   ```
   public final class Container {
   let realm: Realm

   public convenience init() throws {
       try self.init(realm: Realm())
   }

   internal init(realm: Realm) {
       self.realm = realm
   }

   public func objects<T: Persistable>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> Results<T.ManagedObject> {
       return realm.objects(type.ManagedObject.self)
   }

   public func write(_ block: (WriteTransaction) throws -> Void) throws {
       let transaction = WriteTransaction(realm: realm)
       try realm.write {
           try block(transaction)
       }
   }

   public func values<T> (_type: T.Type, maching query: T.Query) -> FetchResults<T> {
       var results = realm.objects(T.ManagedObject.self)

       if let predicate = query.predicate {
           results = results.filter(predicate)
       }

       if !results.isEmpty {
           results = results.sorted(by: query.sortDescriptors)
       }

       return FetchResults(results: results)
   }
   ```

   }
3. **WriteTransaction** class handling all of events for adding, updating, deleting ( not implemented yet )

   public final class WriteTransaction {
       let realm: Realm

   ```
   internal init(realm: Realm) {
       self.realm = realm
   }

   public func add<T: Persistable>(_ value: T, update: Bool) {
       realm.add(value.getManagedObject(), update: update)
   }

   public func update<T: Persistable>(_ type: T.Type, values:[T.PropertyValue]) {
       var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]

       values.forEach {
           let pair = $0.propertyValuePair
           dictionary[pair.name] = pair.value
       }

       realm.create(T.ManagedObject.self, value: dictionary, update: true)
   }

   public func delete<T: Persistable>(_ value: T) {
       // TODO: Make it better.
   ```

   //        guard let objc = realm.object(ofType: T.self, forPrimaryKey: value.getId()) else { return }
   //        realm.delete(objc)
       }
   }
4. And for the fetching objects **FetchResults**:

   public final class FetchResults {

   ```
       internal let results: Results<T.ManagedObject>

       public var count: Int {
           return results.count
       }

       internal init(results: Results<T.ManagedObject>) {
           self.results = results
       }

       public func value(at index: Int) -> T {
           return T(managedObject: results[index])
       }
   }
   ```

The example code would be:

First class where I fetch the objects:

**FirstClass**

Here is a global declaration:

**... Event: Object { ... }**

```
var events: [Event]!
```

In one of the method, same class -> Works as a charm:

Let's fetch some objects via this method: (DataBaseManager is a singleton)

```
events = DataBaseManager.Instance.getObjects(Event.self, try! Container(), matching: .eventsFromPastDaysForOwner(username, Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) - 691200))
```

The implementation of `getObjects(...)` :

```
func getObjects<T, C>(_ type: T.Type, _ container: C, matching: T.Query) -> [T] where T : Persistable, C : Container {
        var objects = [T]()
        let fetchedObjects = container.values(_type: type, maching: matching)
        for i in 0..<fetchedObjects.count {
            objects.append(fetchedObjects.value(at: i))
        }
        return objects
    }
```

If there are no objects lets create them:

```
if events.isEmpty {
    events.append(Event(something: Something, something2: Something2))
}
```

We can easly modify them:

```
events[0].something = Something3
```

For this example we stick with empty list. Going forward to the point.

1. Passing created events ( only one element in the list / it doesnt matter how many ) to:

   func getEventsDurations(_ events: [Event]) -> [Event]

which have some calculations on events, but the line which crash is there:

```
events.first?.something = 0
```

The line where we modify the objects with new values.

Why is that happening ? When I modify the realm object on the class when i did fetch it was ok, but in other class got this crash ?

I am sorry for a lot of code, but it's just in case if someone would like to have a look on Data Base structure.

Btw. I could do work around and place every modification inside write transaction:

```
try! container.write({ transaction in

// Doing nothing, just modifying objects.

    })
```

C'mon, that is soo ugly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify a newly created object anywhere before you save it. But if it’s an object fetched from/saved to realm then you **must** use a realm transaction.

Comment: I do have to use realm transaction on fetched objects :o ? It seems like there is a reference between fetched realm object and the on in db. Is it efficient :o?

Comment: It's plenty efficient. If you want to see why the database works the way it does we have lots of documentation on our website (check out this article, for starters: https://academy.realm.io/posts/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/).